# OOP advice - should I change how my program runs?

Tags: java, oop

below I have a small program i wrote for working out the area of shapes....

My question is this the right way to do it, a friend did similar and had multiple shapes which inherited from main shape. OOP?   is mine ok as i will only ask the area of a shape and no more? and how would i change this to make it more OO?

Main Prog /////

```
package areaprog;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;

public class Mainprog {

    public static void main (String [] args){

        //Area Menu Selection
        System.out.println("What shape do you need to know the area of?\n" +
        "1: Square?\n" +
        "2: Rectangle?\n" +
        "3: Triangle?\n" +
        "4: Circle? \n" +
        "5: Exit\n"     
        );

        //User input for menu

        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Number: ");

        //Menu syntax checking
        while (!reader.hasNextDouble())
        {
            System.out.println("Thats not a number you tool.\n");
            System.out.println("Now pick again\n" +
                    "1: Square?\n" +
                    "2: Rectangle?\n" +
                    "3: Triangle?\n" +
                    "4: Circle? \n" +
                    "5: Exit\n"     
                    );

            reader.next(); //ask for next token     
        }               
            double input = reader.nextDouble();
            reader.nextLine();



        //Depending on user selection, depends on what method is called using  switch.
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Square selection and InputMismatch Exception

    try {

        if (input == 1){
            System.out.println("What is a length of 1 side of the Square?\n");
                double s1 = scan.nextDouble();
                double SqAns = AreaCalculator.getSquareArea(s1);
                System.out.println("The area of you square is: " + SqAns);

                       }    
        }           
    catch (InputMismatchException e)
       {
        System.out.println("Why are you trying to be clever? use an interger");


       }

        //Rectangle selection    
            if (input == 2){
            System.out.println("What is the width of your rectangle?.\n");
                double r1 = scan.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("What is the height of your rectangle?\n");
                double r2 = scan.nextDouble();
                double RecAns = AreaCalculator.getRectArea(r1, r2);
            System.out.println("The area of your rectangle is: " + RecAns);    
            }
        //Triangle selection
        if (input == 3){
            System.out.println("What is the base length of the triangle?.");
                double t1 = scan.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("What is the height of your triangle?");
                double t2 = scan.nextDouble();
                double TriAns = AreaCalculator.getTriArea(t1, t2);
            System.out.println("The area of your triangle is " + TriAns);
        }
        //Circle selection
        if (input == 4){
            System.out.println("What is the radius of your circle?.");
                double c1 = scan.nextDouble();
                double CircAns = AreaCalculator.getCircleArea(c1);
            System.out.println("The area of your circle is " + CircAns);    

        }
        //Exit application
        if (input == 5){
            System.out.println("Goodbye.");

        }


    }

}
```

AreaCalculator.java ////

```
 package areaprog;


public class AreaCalculator {

    public static double getRectArea(double width, double height) {
        double aValue = width * height;

        return aValue;


    }

    public static double getCircleArea(double radius){
        double PI = Math.PI;
        double aValue = PI * Math.pow(radius, 2);

        return aValue;


    }

    public static double getSquareArea(double side) {
        double aValue = Math.pow(side, 2);

        return aValue;


    }

    public static double getTriArea(double base , double height) {
        double aValue = (base/2)* height;

        return aValue;


    }
}
```

Comment: You'd be better off using an `enum` for your shapes.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon Why an enum instead of a class?

Comment: Because it is a set of classes which all do similar things. E.G. They all need a `getArea` method.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon If it's a set of classes representing shapes, presumably they'd have `getArea()`. I'm asking why enums *instead*.

Comment: "Thats not a number you tool" - I think you wanted to write "fool".

Comment: @DaveNewton - It's difficult to explain - perhaps if you try both techniques you will see that `enum` produces the clearest and most flexible solution. Good demo [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/enums.html).

Comment: @bane Not if OP is calling the user a tool.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon I know what an enum is and does, I'm asking why you're advocating an enum over a class in this case, and I can't think of any good reason, especially for a beginner programmer.

Answer (score 1):

Having multiple classes inheriting from a single base class or interface is definitely a better design here. Use classes to encapsulate given functionality or objects(in that case `triangle`, `square` etc. Also when you have multiple classes sharing some functionality better extract it as a common interface to achieve better level of abstraction.

Comment: sorry im new to programming never mind oop so bear with me :)   but all the formulas are different so what would i be inherating from the main class?

Comment: The method getArea, that returns a double. You pass for instance base and high(for a triangle) to its **constructor** as this is what will define a triangle(in fact I think passing the three side lengths is a better option)

Comment: @tmcraig A contract that says `getArea()` returns a shape-appropriate area. This means you wouldn't need to check for the shape type, you just get its area.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is to use an interface of 'shape' like this

```
interface Shape {

double[] dimensions;
double calcArea();
}
```

And have all your shapes implement this interface.

say

```
class Circle implements Shape {
...
}
```

and implement different calcArea() methods for each shape

In your runner, you init a Circle, box, etc...

When you need area, you don't have to care about which shape is actually behind it, just call the method shape.calcArea() and it will find the right one.